# Save Outlook attachment in MS Access using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I am running MS Access 2010.  Using VBA I am trying to pull attachments out of MS Exchange 2013 and insert them into the Access table "TBL_APPT_ATTACHMENT".

The table "TBL_APPT_ATTACHMENT" looks like this:
 Attachment_title     Memo
 Attachment_filename  Memo
 Attachment_blob      OLE Object

Everything seems to work correctly except I can not figure out how to save the actual file into the column ATTACHMENT_BLOB.  Here is my VBA function that I am calling  (See question marks below).

```
Private Function createRecord(fItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem)

  Set rsAtt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TBL_APPT_ATTACHMENT")
  rsAtt.OpenRecordset

  For Each Attachment In fItem.Attachments
    Call MsgBox("FileName: " & Attachment.FileName, vbOKOnly, "Error")
    Call MsgBox("DisplayName: " & Attachment.DisplayName, vbOKOnly, "Error")
    Call MsgBox("Index: " & Attachment.Index, vbOKOnly, "Error")

    rsAtt.AddNew
    rsAtt!APPT_ITEM_ID = aID
    rsAtt!APPT_FIELD_id = rsOl!ID
    rsAtt!ATTACHMENT_TITLE = Attachment.DisplayName
    rsAtt!ATTACHMENT_FILENAME = Attachment.FileName
    rsAttID = rsAtt!ID
    rsAtt.Update

    'Save file to harddrive.
    filePath = "c:\temp\" + Attachment.FileName
    Attachment.SaveAsFile (filePath)

    Set rsParent = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, ATTACHMENT_BLOB FROM TBL_APPT_ATTACHMENT WHERE ID = " & rsAttID)
    rsParent.OpenRecordset
    Do While Not rsParent.EOF
      rsParent.Edit

      'Load file into Database.

'???  This next statement gives me a "Type Mismatch" error.  Why?????
      Set rsChild = rsParent.Fields("ATTACHMENT_BLOB").Value

      rsChild.AddNew
      rsChild.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile (filePath)
      rsChild.Update
      rsParent.Update
      rsParent.MoveNext
    Loop
  Next
End Function
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the attachment is really a file (whether its an OLE object or not). While it may be possible to perform a copy-paste of the object from Outlook into Access, my recommendation is to save the attachment as a file:

```vb
dim filepath as String
dim filename as String
filepath = "C:\appropriatefolder\"
filename = Attachment.FileName
Attachment.SaveAsFile filepath & filename
```

Now you're in a position to save the attachment in Access, but I seriously don't recommend using the Attachment field type. It can be rather tricky to use. So my solution to the same problem was to create a field of type `Hyperlink`. Then your statement in your macro will simply be:

```vb
rsAtt!ATTACHMENT_LINK = filename & "#" & filepath & filename
```

The hyperlink definition is important and uses the format:

```
displayString # fullPathToFile [ # optionalPositionInsideFile ]
```

> **EDIT: Using the Attachment Field Type in Access**

The `Attachment` field type in an Access table can be understood if you consider it an embedded `recordset` within that single record. Therefore, every time you add a new record (or read an existing record), you have to handle the `Attachment` field a bit differently. In fact, the `.Value` of the `Attachment` field is the `recordset` itself.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    AddAttachment "C:\Temp\DepTree.txt"
End Sub

Sub AddAttachment(filename As String)
    Dim tblAppointments As DAO.Recordset
    Dim attachmentField As DAO.Recordset
    Dim tblField As Field

    Set tblAppointments = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TBL_APPT_ATTACHMENT", dbOpenDynaset)

    tblAppointments.AddNew
    tblAppointments![APPT_ITEM_ID] = "new item id"
    tblAppointments![APPT_FIELD_ID] = "new field id"
    tblAppointments![ATTACHMENT_TITLE] = "new attachment"
    tblAppointments![ATTACHMENT_FILENAME] = filename

    '--- the attachment field itself is a recordset, because you can add multiple
    '    attachments to this single record. so connect to the recordset using the
    '    .Value of the parent record field, then use it like a recordset
    Set attachmentField = tblAppointments![ATTACHMENT_BLOB].Value
    attachmentField.AddNew
    attachmentField.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile filename
    attachmentField.Update

    tblAppointments.Update

    tblAppointments.Close
    Set tblAppointments = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The Hyperlink solution is not an option for me.  Once the data/documents are loaded from MS Exchange into the MS Access database, the database will be placed behind a firewall.  I cannot always guarantee that the hyperlink will be valid.  I need the actual document loaded into the database.

Comment: My example checks out very close to the code in your OP. I think your difference is possibly the missing declaration of `rsChild`. In the absence of a `Dim` statement, the variable is a `Variant`. Try adding `Dim rsChild as DAO.RecordSet` to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT.   If I add the statement:  'Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset',  I get a compile error:  "Method or data member not found"  for the line 'rschild.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile(filePath)' with 'LoadFromFile' being highlighted.        If I removed the statement:  'Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset', I get a runtime error: "Type mismatch" on line 'Set rsChild = rsParent.Fields("ATTACHMENT_BLOB").Value'

Comment: This is curious, because if your code is in Access, then the correct references should already be loaded by default in the VBA editor. In the VBA editor on the menu, go to Tools->References and make sure the Microsoft Office Access database engine Object Library is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing.

```
Private Function createRecord(fItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem)

  Set rsAtt = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TBL_APPT_ATTACHMENT")
  rsAtt.OpenRecordset

  For Each Attachment In fItem.Attachments

    'Save file to harddrive.
    filePath = "c:\temp\" + Attachment.FileName
    Attachment.SaveAsFile (filePath)

    rsAtt.AddNew
    rsAtt!APPT_ITEM_ID = aID
    rsAtt!APPT_FIELD_id = rsOl!ID
    rsAtt!ATTACHMENT_TITLE = Attachment.DisplayName
    rsAtt!ATTACHMENT_FILENAME = Attachment.FileName

    Call FileToBlob(filePath, rsAtt!ATTACHMENT_BLOB)

    rsAttID = rsAtt!ID
    rsAtt.Update

  Next
End Function

Public Function FileToBlob(strFile As String, ByRef Field As Object)
    On Error GoTo FileToBlobError

    If Len(Dir(strFile)) > 0 Then
        Dim nFileNum As Integer
        Dim byteData() As Byte

        nFileNum = FreeFile()
        Open strFile For Binary Access Read As nFileNum
        If LOF(nFileNum) > 0 Then
            ReDim byteData(1 To LOF(nFileNum))
            Get #nFileNum, , byteData
            Field = byteData
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: File not found", vbCritical, _
               "Error reading file in FileToBlob"
    End If

  FileToBlobExit:
    If nFileNum > 0 Then Close nFileNum
    Exit Function

  FileToBlobError:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
           "Error reading file in FileToBlob"
    Resume FileToBlobExit

End Function
```